# asp.net mvc findpartialview performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is using the AreaViewEngine proposed by Phil Haack [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx). It works fine, but the app seems kind of sluggish, so I was doing some profiling using dotTrace. I pushed the app to our dev server, changed the debug flag to false in web.config (compilation debug="false"), started up the profiler, and used jmeter to generate a few thousand hits. What I found is listed below:

[image]

Notice how VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView took over 320 seconds. I'm unable to drill down any farther to see what underlying code is causing the problem, but I suspect it's related to the issue mentioned [here](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/22/how-to-improve-htmlhelper.renderpartial-performances-donrsquot-run-in-debug-mode.aspx).

The blog specifically states that running in release mode will cause view path resolution to be cached, but this doesn't seem to be the case (or if it is, something else is taking a hell of a lot of time within the FindPartialView function.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

I never did find the cause of the problem, but I ended up downloading the MVC source code for release 1.0 and it works fine. Must be a discrepancy between the installable binary and the source code for v1.0. or something borked with my install (though the issue manifested itself on multiple machines).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to help performance when you're using RenderPartial() or View() is to return the path to the view that way it doesn't have to search for it.  When you provide only the file name it has to determine it's only a file name then search for the view in a list of folders.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but if you look at the article I linked, the work that is required to search for the view should only happen once if debug is turned off, because the result should be cached. What I'm trying to get at is why the cache doesn't appear to be working. Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong? That's my question.